# How to return unique words from the text file using Python

Tags: python, text-files, unique

How do I return all the unique words from a text file using Python?
For example:

> I am not a robot
>
> I am a human

Should return:

> I
>
> am
>
> not
>
> a
>
> robot
>
> human

Here is what I've done so far:

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    input_file = open(input_filename, 'r')
    file_contents = input_file.read()
    input_file.close()
    word_list = file_contents.split()

    file = open(output_filename, 'w')

    for word in word_list:
        if word not in word_list:
            file.write(str(word) + "\n")
    file.close()
```

The text file the Python creates has nothing in it. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 17):

```
for word in word_list:
    if word not in word_list:
```

every `word` is in `word_list`, by definition from the first line.

Instead of that logic, use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
unique_words = set(word_list)
for word in unique_words:
    file.write(str(word) + "\n")
```

`set`s only hold unique members, which is exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Note that order won't be preserved, but you didn't specify if that's a requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the set command as this homework is to improve our for loop skills.

Comment: I have no problem helping with homework questions, but you've got to define the constraints clearly up front when the right way to do something is arbitrarily disallowed

Comment: My mistake we can use any method. Got an email 30 minutes ago.

Answer (score 6):

Simply iterate over the lines in the file and use set to keep only the unique ones.

```
from itertools import chain

def unique_words(lines):
    return set(chain(*(line.split() for line in lines if line)))
```

Then simply do the following to read all unique lines from a file and print them

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    print(unique_words(f))
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a typical application for a collection:

```
...
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict()
for word in wordlist: d[word] = None 
# use this if you also want to count the words:
# for word in wordlist: d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1 
for k in d.keys(): print k
```

You could also use a collection.Counter(), which would also count the elements you feed in. The order of the words would get lost though. I added a line for counting and keeping the order.

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "I am not a robot\n I am a human"
list_str = string.split()
print list(set(list_str))
```

Comment: Doesn't even work on OP's example input. Hint: `.split()` is different from `.split(' ')`

Comment: @trentcl hwz it now?...thnx got ur point..., really a nice point diff between `.split()` and `.split(' ')`

Comment: Better, but honestly, this question is over 3 years old and the accepted answer is basically the same as yours, except with explanation, so I upvoted that one instead. If you have something constructive to add, like maybe building the set without first loading the whole file into memory, this would be a good answer; if it boils down to just "use `set`" I don't know why you bothered.

Answer (score 1):

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    input_file = open(input_filename, 'r')
    file_contents = input_file.read()
    input_file.close()
    duplicates = []
    word_list = file_contents.split()
    file = open(output_filename, 'w')
    for word in word_list:
        if word not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(word)
            file.write(str(word) + "\n")
    file.close()
```

This code loops over every word, and if it is not in a list `duplicates`, it appends the word and writes it to a file.

Comment: Instead of having an extra list is it possible to use: `file = open(output_filename, 'a')` ? (This was my first code (which didn't work))

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex and Set:

```
import re
words = re.findall('\w+', text.lower())
uniq_words = set(words)
```

Other way is creating a Dict and inserting the words like keys:

```
for i in range(len(doc)):
        frase = doc[i].split(" ")
        for palavra in frase:
            if palavra not in dict_word:
                dict_word[palavra] = 1
print dict_word.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is word_list already has all possible words of the input file. When iterating over the loop you are basically checking if a word in word_list is not present in itself. So it'll always be false. This should work.. (Note that this wll also preserve the order).

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):
  z = []
  with open(input_filename,'r') as fileIn, open(output_filename,'w') as fileOut:
      for line in fileIn:
          for word in line.split():
              if word not in z:
                 z.append(word)
                 fileOut.write(word+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set. You don't need to import anything to do this.

```
#Open the file
my_File = open(file_Name, 'r')
#Read the file
read_File = my_File.read()
#Split the words
words = read_File.split()
#Using a set will only save the unique words
unique_words = set(words)
#You can then print the set as a whole or loop through the set etc
for word in unique_words:
     print(word)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
try:
    with open("gridlex.txt",mode="r",encoding="utf-8")as india:

        for data in india:
            if chr(data)==chr(data):
                print("no of chrats",len(chr(data)))
            else:
                print("data")
except IOError:
    print("sorry")
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23042940)