# Filter unique lines from a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print the unique lines present within the text file.

For example: if the content of my text file is:

```
12345
12345
12474
54675
35949
35949
74564
```

I want my Python program to print:

```
12474
54675
74564
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: And your own attempt?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I hope you don't mind I closed the question. I feel you wanted to provide an answer :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - It does deserve closure, but I don't think that's an accurate dupe. This question wants entries with a count greater than one to be removed entirely.

Comment: You may also check: [How to return unique words from the text file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978602/how-to-return-unique-words-from-the-text-file-using-python)

Comment: Right! Do you want me to reopen it so you can close it with the proper original question?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : It's certainly not the duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: okay, reopening. After that I cannot close anymore. Don't complain about duplicate answers :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think that's justified, since we have fun down there trying to solve the riddle with different approaches.. even though it probably defeats the purpose of giving the fish instead of the fishing rod

Comment: Okay, I try to give the fish, but before OP tries to eat it, the fish explains the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

seen = OrderedDict()
for line in open('file.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    seen[line] = seen.get(line, 0) + 1

print("\n".join([k for k,v in seen.items() if v == 1]))
```

prints

```
12474
54675
74564
```

**Update**: thanks to the comments below, this is even nicer:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

with open('file.txt') as f:
    seen = OrderedCounter([line.strip() for line in f])
    print("\n".join([k for k,v in seen.items() if v == 1]))
```

Comment: indeed! didn't catch that, hold on

Comment: Yes Eric is right. This code isn't what i want

Comment: @AltayKarakalpaklı I updated the code so it now does what it should

Comment: @AltayKarakalpaklı the comments above are of course right: did you actually try anything before you posted the question?

Comment: @hansaplast : Your code works now, but you shouldn't write any code if the OP didn't bother to. Some text explaining what your method would do would have been better IMHO.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I will try to hold back next time. At least this question was formulated clearly which is somehow an exception on SO these days :)

Comment: Better way would have been to use `Counter` along with `OrderedDict` together to get order count of each word/line. No need of set here

Comment: For reference, here's what I wrote before you updated the answer : You didn't provide any code, so you'll only get pointers. You could use a dictionary, with strings as keys and count as values. The default value would be 0. You could iterate over your file, and for every line, you increase the value of the corresponding string by 1. Once you read all the file, you can iterate over the values in your dictionary : if it's 1, you can output the key.

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: I thought of combining `Counter` and `OrderedDict` but thought it would not be possible, turns out it is, this is a lot nicer of course, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

You may use `OrderedDict` and `Counter` for removing the duplicates and maintaining order as:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

with open('/tmp/hello.txt') as f:
    ordered_counter = OrderedCounter(f.readlines())

new_list = [k.strip() for k, v in ordered_counter.items() if v==1]
# ['12474', '54675', '74564']
```

Comment: I was 1 minute faster :-P

Comment: @hansaplast BTW I wrote it just to share with you on how to do it. I guess you already figured that out

Comment: yeah, thanks for the pointers in the comments, it was a fun exercise

Comment: Interesting. What's the purpose of `pass` here?

Comment: @EricDuminil Since body of this class is empty, you need `pass` to complete the scope of class. Check : [How To Use The Pass Statement In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use `count()` to check the number of occurrences of each element in the list, and remove each occurrence using `index()` in a for loop:

```
with open("file.txt","r")as f:
    data=f.readlines()
    for x in data:
        if data.count(x)>1:   #if item is a duplicate
            for i in range(data.count(x)):  
                data.pop(data.index(x))  #find indexes of duplicates, and remove them 
with open("file.txt","w")as f:
    f.write("".join(data)) #write data back to file as string
```

file.txt:

```
12474
54675
74564
```

Comment: You could use `readlines()` directly, couldn't you?

Comment: Yes, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient since it uses `count` but simple:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    orig = list(f)
    filtered = [x for x in orig if orig.count(x)==1]

print("".join(filtered))
```

- convert the file to a list of lines
- create list comprehension: keep only lines occurring once
- print the list (joining with empty string since linefeeds are still in the lines)