# Unique words in a text file

Tags: text-files, unique

I was wondering if there is a way to find (and display) all the unique words (words that appear once) in a text file? Could this be done just using the command line? Or would I have to use something like a python script?

Comment: You can also try this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978602/how-to-return-unique-words-from-the-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write an application then the easiest way that I can think to accomplish this is to use powershell. See this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique

The example that Microsoft provides populates a variable with the list of unique words:

```
$A = $(foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\Test1\File1.txt) {$line.tolower().split(" ")}) | sort | Get-Unique
```

You may wish you use additional delimiters though to split on punctuation such as this:

```
$A = $(foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\test.txt) {$line.tolower().split(" .,?!;:")}) | sort | Get-Unique
```

Place this in a file with the extension .ps1 and you can run it from the command line. In order to get the values out of the variable just a second line with the variable to echo the result to the screen:

```
$A
```

To get the count of items in the array you could do this:

```
$A.count
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. For simple tasks such as this one PowerShell is perfect. It is faster to cobble together a little script than to write an application that has to be compiled.

Comment: Is there a way to disregard punctuation altogether?

Comment: Without making this much more complicated the best I could recommend is replacing the punctuation in the $line variable with an empty string by doing something like this:

$line.tolower().replace(".","")