# How can I make my code find the unique words in each file and list them?

Tags: python, list, loops, unique

The code is supposed to ask a user for a file, find all the unique words in the file and sort them in a list alphabetically. However for each run,the return output is always "None".

I've tried indenting the for loop "for x in unique" under the first for loop but the outcome is the same. I haven't tried much else cause I'm not really sure what the issue is .

```
inp=input('Enter file: ')
fhand=open(inp)
for line in fhand:
    words=line.split()#List containing all the words in the line
    unique=list()#List which will store all the unique words in the file
    for word in words:#For each word in list containing the words in the line
        if words.count(word)==1:
            unique.append(word)#To add the word to the unique list
        else:
            continue
for x in unique:#For each word in the unique list
    y=unique.count(x)
    if y==1:
        continue
    else:
        for y in unique: #This loop is to remove all duplicates from the the unique list
            unique.remove(x)
print(unique.sort())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return unique words from the text file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978602/how-to-return-unique-words-from-the-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Why not `set`? What I can think of is something like what follows:

```py
inp=input('Enter file: ')
fhand=open(inp).read()
sorted(set(fhand.split()))
```

Comment: This is an assignment that I have to do and we haven't learned about sets yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is that you are declaring the variable unique inside the for each loop, and hence the interpreter does not find any variable named 'unique' outside the for each loop.

Here's the modified code

```
inp=input('Enter file: ')
fhand=open(inp)
unique=list()
for line in fhand:
    words=line.split()#List containing all the words in the line
    for word in words:#For each word in list containing the words in the line
        if words.count(word)==1:
            unique.append(word)#To add the word to the unique list
        else:
            continue
for x in unique:#For each word in the unique list
    y=unique.count(x)
    if y==1:
        continue
    else:
        for y in unique: #This loop is to remove all duplicates from the the unique list
            unique.remove(x)
print(unique.sort())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to print a sorting function, which always return None. Sort the list before printing it and your code will work. The last loop is not needed, since if y is larger than 1 then you want it removed.

```
# Exercise 4
unique = list()
fhand = open('romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    words = line.split() # Splits upp the lines in lists
    for word in words:
        if words.count(word) == 1:
            unique.append(word) # Adds every word into the unique list
        else:
            continue
for x in unique:
    y = unique.count(x) # Every word adds 1 to y every time it shows
    if y == 1:
        continue
    else:
       unique.remove(x)     # If y is larger than 1, it will be removed so its 1 again
unique.sort() # Sort unique list
print(unique) # Print unique list that is now sorted and only showing unique words
```