# how to print only unique words in a class string

Tags: python, string, class, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

this is how I obtained the data input at the beginning:

```
with open("wordslist.txt") as f:
    words_list = {word.removesuffix("\n") for word in f}

with open("negation_handling.csv") as g:
    for tweete in g:
        for word in tweete.split():
            if word not in words_list:
                print(word)
```

This code resulting in a data with the type of `<class 'str'>`. this class string contains a lot of words that have duplicates. I wanted to print all of the words, but no words are repeated (delete all the duplicates). here is how the class looks, the class name is `word`:

```
gfg
best
gfg
I
am
I
two
two
three
..............
```

my list of strings contains around 4500 words, and it is separated by a newline (enter) just like in the example of my question. now I cannot copy paste the strings because they are too many, so I store it in a class called "word" but I don't know how to call the class. I wanted the code to do a looping and remove all the duplicate words so the output would be like this:

```
gfg best I am two three..........
```

this is what I tried:

```
input_list_of_strings = word

# Create empty list to store unique 
unique_words = []

# Loop through each word and check if it exists in unique words list
for word in input_list_of_strings:
    if word not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(word)

# Print the result
print(unique_words)
```

but the results are like this:

```
 ['e']
```

how can I call the class `word` correctly?

Comment: Paste your tried code here

Comment: This is a complete guess, but if you have a list of strings and are trying to remove duplicates while preserving order, you can do `newlist = list(dict.fromkeys(oldlist))`. If this isn't what you're trying to do, you're going to need to provide a lot more context.

Comment: edited my question with the codes and context!

Comment: i tried your code, that's the idea, but it prints out characters instead of words and didn't iterate through the whole class strings

Comment: Your first two lines of code are generating a set, not a string. The rest is just printing strings. There's no variable holding a string or a list of strings at the end. What's `word` in your attempt?

Comment: We need to know whether your words are in a list, a string, or in a file. Each situation will require a (maybe similar but) slightly different approach.

Comment: i don't even know at this point... I checked he data type of word with this code "print(type(word))" and the output is this "<class 'str'>" so I assumed "word" is a class.

Comment: `word` is a variable, a name that references a string. Now I see that you defined it inside the loop. So `word` is probably storing the last printed word. Not all the words that were originally in your file (try `print(word)`). Also, you redefine it over and over again, so it's not a good idea to do `input_list_of_strings = word` if `word` is going to be a placeholder for a looping variable.

Comment: yes you are right! if I print "word" outside of the loop, it only stored the last printed word. I tried "print(word)" but the result is still the same, only last word is printed. okay so what should I do?:)

Comment: If the prints are the words you want, try this: add `list_of_words = []` at the beginning of your code. Then when you read `"negation_handling.csv"`, in the last line, replace `print(word)` by `list_of_words.append(word)`. Then try [@DSergei answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75505650/15032126) using `list_of_words`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return unique words from the text file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978602/how-to-return-unique-words-from-the-text-file-using-python)

Comment: it worked! now the data type is a list! thank you so much for being patient with me!:)

Comment: i'll check the link you attached later! thank you again!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your input is a list of strings you could simply remember all unique strings using loop:

```
input_list_of_strings = ['gfg', 'best', 'gfg', 'I', 'am', 'I', 'two', 'two', 'three']

# Create empty list to store unique 
unique_words = []

# Loop through each word and check if it exists in unique words list
for word in input_list_of_strings:
    if word not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(word)

# Print the result
print(unique_words)
```

2. Also, you could use python [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp), but pay attention that it won't **save the initial word order**

```
input_list_of_strings = ['gfg', 'best', 'gfg', 'I', 'am', 'I', 'two', 'two', 'three']


# Create a set of unique words from the list
unique_words = set(input_list_of_strings)

unique_words_list = list(unique_words)

# Print the result
print(unique_words_list)
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: thanks for your answer! I tried both of your codes, but the result is only like this: "gf". it prints out the word as a words and not characters, but it didn't iterate through the list, so it only prints out one word. can you do it with looping?

Comment: and I tried changing the "hello world hello python world" with "word", but it printed out "world" I'm confused:(

Comment: As far as I get, you want words "I wanted to print all of the words", not "it prints out the word as a words and not characters". What do you actually want?

And could you please tell, Input words is something from terminal input() or a list of strings?

Comment: yes I wanted to print all the words, but the code you provided only printed out one word (the loop doesn't seem to be working). the input (class named word) is a list of strings.

Comment: just tried it, your code works perfectly for your example ("hello world hello python world"), but when I changed the input to my data, the output is like this: "world" meanwhile I don't have that word in my data:)

Comment: I've changed the code, if you have list of strings as an input. Try it now, please =)

Comment: I just clocked that there is nothing wrong with your code, it has something to do with my input. my list of strings contains around 4500 words, and it is separated by a newline (enter) just like in the example of my question. now I cannot copy paste the strings because they are too many, so I store it in a class called "word" but I don't know how to call the class, can you help me with it?

Comment: I edited my question, with your code:)

Comment: Just to clarify, by list you mean
1. python type [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) - the code is provided
2. or words from keyboard
?

    Class is also store data in some variables. In which way have you saved initial input?

Comment: wait I'll add my code for the data input:)

Comment: I already added how I obtained the data:)

Comment: Could you also provide the code of your class word?

Just for your information, better to [name classes](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/) with the capital letter at front, for example, class Word

Comment: @ZulfiA if your "list" is an open file with one word per line, just adapt this code: replace `for word in input_list_of_strings` for `for word in f`, where f is the name of the opened file (after `with open("wordslist.txt") as f:`)

Comment: And by class you mean [python class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) or something else?

Comment: can you please write your answer in a new reply? @Ignatius Reilly

Comment: yes it's a python class:)

Comment: Do you have a class called `word`??? If so, please add the definition of the class.